# Update table A by Joining Table B and Table A

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A, Table B
My database looks some thing like this
Table A
key1
key2
key5
key6

Table B
key3
key4

Data in A.key2 is same as data in B.key3 and A.key5 has same data as B.key 4
I want to update key1 in Table A to another row in table A based on some condition on key6 of table A

I want to update some rows in Table A with Values which I would get by joining Table A with Table B.

I tried running a query like

```
UPDATE table A set a.key1 = c.key1 FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.key2 = b.key3 JOIN A c ON b.key4 = c.key5 WHERE A.key6 = somevalue;
```

sql throws an error -
column a of relation A does not exist

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you are trying to do and a *single* database tag.  I removed the incompatible tags as a favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for Postgresql:

```
UPDATE A a
SET key1 = c.key1 
FROM B b 
JOIN A c ON b.key4 = c.key5 
WHERE a.key2 = b.key3  AND a.key6 = somevalue;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with a small change
instead of A.key6
I had to use a.key6